# confluent-3.2.0 S3 Connector default partition settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have been able to successfully write my topic date stream to my s3 bucket, however, the data is partition numerically (partition=0).

current display: (Amazon S3 > bucket-name > topics > test > partition=0

Is it possible to partition the data by Date(yyyy-mm-dd)? And if so where would be the configuration to override the default partition settings.

Thank you for your help,
Warsame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.1/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/configuration_options.html#partitioner), the connector has a pluggable partitioner and a built-in `TimeBasedPartitioner` that can partition the data based upon ingestion time. The various [partitioner configuration parameters](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/configuration_options.html#partitioner) allow you to control things like the directory structure. There's even a [DailyPartitioner](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/v3.2.2/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/DailyPartitioner.java) that is a specialization of `TimeBasedPartitioner` that produces a path structure like `/year=2017/month=12/day=07`.

If none of these work, you always have the option of implementing a custom `Partitioner` class or specializing the `TimeBasedPartitioner` class (or any of its subclasses) if that's easier.

Comment: Thanks for the links and answer. This helped allot.